# Official Documentation on tkinter.filedialog

Tags: python, tkinter

Where can I find official documentation on `tkinter.filedialog` module including all the methods and options?

Here I can find just a reference to it.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html?highlight=filedialog

Comment: `import tkinter.filedialog` and then `help(tkinter.filedialog)`.

Comment: @progmatico, In that, it informs about the functions like `askdirectory(**options)` but does not tell about the options available in it. Where can I find the details of options?

Comment: Those options are the same used by the tk/tcl toolkit. Python just passes the options to that library, while opening the corresponding dialogs. See for example options for the correponding tk_chooseDir dialog in [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/chooseDirectory.htm). Pass your options as keywords without the `-`. More help for other widgets [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/contents.htm)

Comment: If the question was answered you can post the answer yourself and mark it as accepted. This will make it clear for everyone that your problem was solved (and you get some points with it).

Comment: @progmatico, can you please add your comment as answer?

Comment: Just post it yourself and mark as Community Wiki.

Comment: @Kamal thanks for your attribution. I thought it was ok as a comment, so I'm ok too with making it a community wiki.

Comment: Actually the official tkinter documentation is effbot.org but sadly the article for filedialog is more than disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By @progmatico,

Those options are the same used by the tk/tcl toolkit. Python just passes the options to that library, while opening the corresponding dialogs. See for example options for the correponding tk_chooseDir dialog in [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/chooseDirectory.htm). Pass your options as keywords without the `-`. More help for other widgets [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/contents.htm)

Answer (score -1):

You can find everything in the web page you mentioned:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html?highlight=filedialog

There is a link to the source code at the beginning of every module. If you are looking for the options, just search for the word 'options' on the code.

Comment: Isn't the point of documentation so you don't have to search through the source code?

Comment: The official documentation lacks of detail. Till now, this is the best way I've found to see the different options. At least, it's functional till the documentation gets better. Just go here https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/tkinter/filedialog.py, search for the word 'options' on your browser and the options are all listed there.